# scangearmp2 can scan from my Canon Pixma TS5150 but only basic scans

Tags: scanner, canon

I have installed the scangearmp2 tool to use my Canon Pixma TS5150 scanner and I managed to get it working. But unlike some screenshot I've seen it only provides a very crude interface. It can only scan the entire page in 300 dpi, no preview and no other options.

From xsane I do get a preview but any attempt to select an area to scan is ignored. Resolution is listed only up to 300 dpi and it only uses 300 dpi as far as I can tell.

Is this not (yet) supported for this scanner or am I doing something wrong? I am running Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04). By mistake I installed the 32-bit OS but I assume this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It requires ScanGear MP version **3.50**: https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts5150.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(32-bit) (download and install the .deb file as usual)

Comment: But I do have version 3.50.

Comment: I see further down on that page they state that it requires Ubuntu 17.04. That doesn't sound reasonable and if it was true I'd expect some error due to missing dependencies.

Comment: You mentioned "scangearmp2"?? Installing with the .deb installer may require a certain version but using the version independent installer should do it anyway. Now, this maybe also a good opportunity to install a newer and 64-bit OS.

Comment: Yes the name of the program is scangearmp2. The installation is done with a shell script (run as root) which installed it and also helped me find and configure the scanner. Yes, I plan to replace my other computer once Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04) is out and so it may be better then. And it's more important that the printer works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open source sane backend](https://github.com/ThierryHFR/scangearmp2) for Canon Pixma scanners, based on the source code of scangearmp2, which allows changing the DPI setting, with [binary releases](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/thierry1970/) for several distros.